# Can the OP accept a previously rejected edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Suppose an edit to one of your posts (be it question or answer) was suggested but rejected while you were not active. After reviewing the edit yourself, you think it actually would improve your post. Is there a way to accept such an edit retrospectively such that also the original edit-author gets credit for it (i.e., is shown left to the author as the person who did the last edit)?

Comment: Related on Meta Server Fault: [I accidentally rejected a suggested edit that should have been approved. What do I do now?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5299/i-accidentally-rejected-a-suggested-edit-that-should-have-been-approved-what-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Once an edit is rejected it's rejected for good.  At this point you have two options.  You can either:

- Make the edit yourself

This is probably what you'll end up doing most of the time although it gives no credit to the original user who suggested it.

- You can try to get a hold of the user in chat and ask them to resubmit the edit.

Of course, this will only work if the user has a chat account (has visited chat at least once) and has visited in the last three days.  Otherwise the user won't get your ping.

Technically you *could* try to contact that user in a comment, but I don't recommend that for this situation.

Comment: I'm absolutely certain this is an old now wrong answer.

Comment: @Joshua yes. If you follow the duplicate chain in the question you'll find this feature was added about a year ago.

Comment: Indeed; that's why I wrote "now wrong". Unfortunately, Google thinks this page is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Once the suggested edit is rejected from the necessary number of users, it is rejected.

What you can do, if you think the suggested edit was helpful, is editing your own post, and change it as that user done. The user doesn't get any reputation gain, if you do so, though.