# Retroactively approve suggested and rejected edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

There were [already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174234/can-the-op-accept-a-previously-rejected-edit?lq=1) [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139690/can-i-challenge-the-rejection-of-a-suggested-edit?lq=1) [support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135967/user-suggested-great-corrective-edit-to-my-answer-but-the-edit-was-rejected-wh) questions on **applying rejected suggested edits to one's own post**.

Could this functionality be implemented? It is always possible to do so by hand, but this

1. does not credit the editor (rep, edit count, etc)
2. is a bit tedious

#### Implementation

could be to use some of the free space at the suggested edit page left to the *Next*-button. Have a button there with *No, this looks good, accept*, for example.

[image: place to put]

#### Advantages

- Saves the tedium of having to manually apply rejected edits by hand.
- Gives credit where credit is due.
- Only appears on your own posts, does not clutter the UI. Design already there.

#### Disadvantages

- Implementation overhead
- Does not school the editor to rather leave a comment, but: *Many would probably prefer to have the edit spelled out rather than hinted in a comment*

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Good suggestion. Is there anything else that you think needs improvement?